# jQuery UI Sortable: dragged element disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I set the `<div class="container">` `.sortable()`, and there are some elements in the container.

When I drag the inner element, intend to sort the element with the others, once the dragged one out the container, **it can not be seen**.

But when I drop it into place holder, it could be seen again. [Online case is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/UHYVH/).

Anyone have met the problem before? Or anyone can help me with the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Drop the `overflow: hidden;` on `.container` and it will work. The problem is that during the drag you're moving a child of `.container` outside of the `.container` element, you've told the browser to hide any overflow while you're forcing an overflow during the drag and the browser is doing what you told it to do.

General advice: leave `overflow` alone unless you know what it does and why you need to use it.

Comment: using this work around (I did not want to touch any styling) did the trick for me `$("#myDraggableElem").draggable({ appendTo: 'body', helper: 'clone', zIndex: 300 });` . Note that a new element is created when you drag an element, it may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

the trick is to set helper to `'clone'` and use a temporary swaplist for the drag.. modified version of your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UHYVH/13/)

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
    helper: "clone"
});
```

Comment: The appendTo on a separate div is what worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, appendTo did not and my overflow wasn't set to hidden.

Comment: Does not do anything.. not sure why but when I drag the elements jump around. See this gif: http://gph.is/2p3dP4u

Answer (score 3):

My dragged items were disappearing in a vertical list and I found that using overflow-y: hidden instead of overflow:hidden worked for me. i.e. only target the y axis.

Answer (score 2):

most probably the problem is due to this: `.container{ margin:0 20px; position:absolute;top:0;height:100%;width:280px;overflow:hidden;}`.

If you set `overflow:auto` it shows the wrapper div with scrollbar and you can view your portlet.